# What makes WPF databinding so powerful?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Just a simple question really, might be to simple really but hey here goes.

What makes WPF binding so powerful vs say Winforms databinding?

What are you likes and dislikes about it?

Any code example that show it's power would be cool.

Comment: Data binding isn't really powerful at all. It's easy to use, but very limited.

Comment: What limitations are you talking about in WPF Guffa?

Comment: The fact that it can be done on any DependencyProperty?

Comment: target should be DependencyProperty, I think it is not limitation, source can implement INotifyPropertyChanged and it works powerful

Answer (score 3):

One of the powerful features of WPF data binding is that it can be two way, that changing target property in code change the value in binded control if property is dependency or implements INotifyPropertyChanged the other powerful feature is converters see [WPF Two way databinding explained](https://web.archive.org/web/20180131233252/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Shuvo/archive/2009/02/16/wpf-two-way-databinding-explained.aspx),[Properties and data binding](https://blog.ramondeklein.nl/?p=70) and the tired one that I think should be mentioned is that you can use WPF databinding with Animation classes

**EDIT**

So WPF databinding has this and many other features that is difficult to implement in winforms

1. Can be two way
2. Can be used in templates
3. Can load data [Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.isasync?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
4. Can have [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.converter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
5. Can be binded directly to XML
6. Can be used in [Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

The power of WPF binding comes when you bind it to something other than a property on a POCO object.

For example, you can bind one controls enabled state to another controls checked state, like so:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb" Content="Enable next section" />
    <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=IsChecked}">
        <Button Content="Click Me!" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```